# Apache Solr doesn't start without explicit error logs

Tags: java, solr, lucene, alfresco, nssm

My Apache Solr service doesn't start well and I don't find any Error in the log file that can explain why (you can find the startup logs below).
When I try to call this server I get a 500 error. I can't connect to the Solr interface (http://localhost:8983/solr).

Everything is installed on a Windows server 2016, I use the 6.6.5 version of Solr on a NSSM service. It works with the 11.0.3 version of JAVA.

I deleted and recreate the index files located at `F:/alfresco-6/solr/alfresco/index` and at `F:/alfresco-6/solr/archive/index`, before restarting the server but that didn't solved the problem.
I uninstalled and reinstalled the service Solr entirely but the problem is still here.
This service is used with Alfresco and PostgreSQL database but it seems that Solr doesn't need them to be started to start.

This configuration as been working on this server during one month before this problem happened.
I have other *Windows Server 2016* on which is deployed the same configuration is that still work well.

If you have any idea of what can be the cause of this problem or on what direction should we search I'll take it.

Startup logs we found at `D:\alfresco-6\alfresco-search-services\logs`:

> 2020-08-11 13:09:37.514 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server
> jetty-9.3.14.v20161028 2020-08-11 13:09:39.623 INFO  (main) [   ]
> o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter  ___      _       Welcome to Apache Solr™
> version 6.6.0 2020-08-11 13:09:39.623 INFO  (main) [   ]
> o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter / **| ***| |* _   Starting in standalone
> mode on port 8983 2020-08-11 13:09:39.623 INFO  (main) [   ]
> o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter _* / _ \ | '*|  Install dir:
> D:\alfresco-6\alfresco-search-services\solr 2020-08-11 13:09:39.639
> INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter |***/___/*|_|    Start
> time: 2020-08-11T13:09:39.623646900Z 2020-08-11 13:09:42.678 WARN
> (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:alfresco]
> o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis
> class [org.apache.solr.analysis.WordDelimiterFilterFactory]. Please
> consult documentation how to replace it accordingly. 2020-08-11
> 13:09:42.709 WARN  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2) [   x:archive]
> o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis
> class [solr.SynonymFilterFactory]. Please consult documentation how to
> replace it accordingly. 2020-08-11 13:09:44.881 WARN
> (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2) [   x:archive]
> o.a.s.h.c.AlfrescoSolrClusteringComponent No default engine for
> document clustering. 2020-08-11 13:09:44.881 WARN
> (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:alfresco]
> o.a.s.h.c.AlfrescoSolrClusteringComponent No default engine for
> document clustering.

Comment: You don't know what "FileNotFoundException" means?

Comment: The "FileNotFoundException" is not the cause of the problem. We had the same DEBUG error on a solr server that started well.